# using strlen the end of a string

Tags: php

i need to strip away the $_GET['id'] value from the end of $k. example `name=address158`, 158 is the id.. so is there away to strlens 158 from 'address' by using $_GET['id'] as the reference?

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
        @$select.=" `".mysql_real_escape_string($k)."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($v)."',";
}
$select = rtrim($select,',');
$select = "UPDATE load_test SET".$select." WHERE Id=".$_GET['id'];
mysql_query($select);
```

Comment: Why would you use strlen for that?

Comment: Why suppress errors in the second line?

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't allow raw, unsanitized data in your queries like that!  That code is just asking to be hacked.  Google "SQL Injection" to learn how to sanitize data for use in your queries.

Comment: So, you stuck to this injection-vulnerable code. Alas.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel is back! I'm happy.

Comment: @shrapnel i'm escaping out the post and value how is it injection vulnerable?

Comment: escaping will help nothing with field names. escaping is not damn magic wand makes your data "safe". it just escape quotes, to make string unbreakable. there are no quotes around field name, thus no escaping could help. You've been told of proper solution already, but being stubborn and ignorant, you ignored it.

Comment: Ah, I came for this. @acctman - if you don't feel like googling SQL Injection like Colin suggested, just consider what would happen if someone invokes your script with `$_GET['id'] == "1 OR Id <> 0"`. For example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
$k = substr($k, 0, -strlen($_GET['id']));
```

I'm assuming that the identifier is always at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of approaches here, depending on how strict your input is.

If you want to split by the `=` character: You could use `strpos` to find the `=` character, or you could use `explode` to split key and value.

If you want to use the ID, then you could use `strrpos` on the ID.